# Find the smallest value under conditions about the index (NA output possible)

Tags: r, dplyr

**Question:**

I am using `dplyr` to do data analysis in R, and I come across the following problem.

My data frame is like this:

```
   item  day  val 
1     A    1   90 
2     A    2  100 
3     A    3  110 
4     A    5   80 
5     A    8   70
6     B    1   75
7     B    3   65
```

The data frame is already arranged in `item, day`. Now I want to mutate a new column, with each row being the smallest value of the same group AND having the day to be **within the next 2 days.**

For the example above, I want the resulting data frame to be:

```
   item  day  val  output
1     A    1   90     100  # the smaller of 100 and 110
2     A    2  100     110  # the only value within 2 days
3     A    3  110      80  # the only value within 2 days
4     A    5   80      NA  # there is no data within 2 days
5     A    8   70      NA  # there is no data within 2 days
6     B    1   75      65  # the only value within 2 days
7     B    3   65      NA  # there is no data within 2 days
```

I understand that I will probably use `group_by` and `mutate`, but how to write the inside function in order to achieve my desired result?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need me to clarify anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df %>%

  # arrange(item, day) %>% # if not already arranged

  # take note of the next two values & corresponding difference in days
  group_by(item) %>%
  mutate(val.1 = lead(val),
         day.1 = lead(day) - day,
         val.2 = lead(val, 2),
         day.2 = lead(day, 2) - day) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # if the value is associated with a day more than 2 days away, change it to NA
  mutate(val.1 = ifelse(day.1 %in% c(1, 2), val.1, NA),
         val.2 = ifelse(day.2 %in% c(1, 2), val.2, NA)) %>%

  # calculate output normally
  group_by(item, day) %>%
  mutate(output = min(val.1, val.2, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # arrange results
  select(item, day, val, output) %>%
  mutate(output = ifelse(output == Inf, NA, output)) %>%
  arrange(item, day)

# A tibble: 7 x 4
  item     day   val output
  <fctr> <int> <int>  <dbl>
1 A          1    90  100  
2 A          2   100  110  
3 A          3   110   80.0
4 A          5    80   NA  
5 A          8    70   NA  
6 B          1    75   65.0
7 B          3    65   NA
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "   item  day  val 
1     A    1   90 
                 2     A    2  100 
                 3     A    3  110 
                 4     A    5   80 
                 5     A    8   70
                 6     B    1   75
                 7     B    3   65", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `complete` from the [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) package to complete the dataset by `day`, and then use `lead` from [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and `rollapply` from [zoo](/questions/tagged/zoo) to find the minimum of the next two days.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)

DF2 <- DF %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  complete(day = full_seq(day, period = 1)) %>%
  mutate(output = rollapply(lead(val), width = 2, FUN = min, na.rm = TRUE, 
                            fill = NA, align = "left")) %>%
  drop_na(val) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(output = ifelse(output == Inf, NA, output))
DF2
# # A tibble: 7 x 4
#   item    day   val output
#   <chr> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
# 1 A      1.00    90  100  
# 2 A      2.00   100  110  
# 3 A      3.00   110   80.0
# 4 A      5.00    80   NA  
# 5 A      8.00    70   NA  
# 6 B      1.00    75   65.0
# 7 B      3.00    65   NA
```

**DATA**

```
DF <- read.table(text = "item  day  val 
1     A    1   90 
                 2     A    2  100 
                 3     A    3  110 
                 4     A    5   80 
                 5     A    8   70
                 6     B    1   75
                 7     B    3   65",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Note that the `rollapply` could be written as `rollapply(val, width = list(1:2), FUN = min, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA)`  where `width = list(1:2)` means use the elements 1 and 2 positions ahead.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks for sharing this great tip.

Answer (score 1):

We'll create a dataset with modified day, so we can left join it on the original dataset, keeping only minimum value.

```
df %>%
  left_join(
    bind_rows(mutate(.,day=day-1),mutate(.,day=day-2)) %>% rename(output=val)) %>%  
  group_by(item,day,val) %>%
  summarize_at("output",min) %>%
  ungroup

# # A tibble: 7 x 4
#     item   day   val output
#   <fctr> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
# 1      A     1    90    100
# 2      A     2   100    110
# 3      A     3   110     80
# 4      A     5    80     NA
# 5      A     8    70     NA
# 6      B     1    75     65
# 7      B     3    65     NA
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "   item  day  val 
1     A    1   90 
2     A    2  100 
3     A    3  110 
4     A    5   80 
5     A    8   70
6     B    1   75
7     B    3   65", header = TRUE)
```